# How to display image and text in the same GridView cell?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datagridview

I am a learner of asp.net and `GridView`. I have one string variable like this

```
string aboutSection = "<p><img class="fr-dib" src="http://i.froala.com/download/2bf8927c7f863ce9b3f3c726f4dccb94b0ec6ef8.PNG?1452253682" style="width: 300px;">this is a text</p>"
```

Which I have got from a `RichTextEditor`(`Froala` Editor). Now I want to display the image and text in the same cell of  `GridView`.

My  `GridView` looks like below:

```
<asp:GridView ID="showDataGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="About">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Literal runat="server" Text='<%#Container.DataItem %>'></asp:Literal>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I am getting this instead of image and text :

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "About") %>'
```

Comment: Sorry about that. I mark the answer as soon I saw your comment.